# Android-studio & Ubuntu: shortuct doesn't work with a dworak layout keyboard

Tags: android, android-studio

I am under ubuntu 13.10 and I am using a dworak-bépo keyboard. It works great with all of my applications. Except for  Android studio that uses the default azerty layout for shortcuts. What I type is right…but only the shortucts doesn't work as the selected keyboard layout is ignored.
Is there a way to change that?

Thanks in advance,

Cédric

Comment: You can change the shorcuts with Settings->Keymap

Comment: Thanks but I will skip this idea. My goal by switching from eclipse to android studio is to make things easier. Redefining ALL the shortuct because of a bug would take too much time.

Comment: I have a similar problem on Mac OS X, only for shortucts, it uses qwerty layout but I have an azerty keyboard. Keymap **doesn't** enable us to fix this bug

Comment: There is a bug report for this: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=90148